# How do I play Are You Afraid of the Dark on Windows 7?

Tags: backwards-compatibility, dosbox, are-you-afraid-of-the-dark

I'm trying to play an old PC game, Are You Afraid of the Dark, but am having trouble getting it to run.

I tried Dfend but did not have any luck. I also tried DOSBox, but was not able to get it to work.

I am using Windows 7 64 bit.

Can someone walk me through the setup please?

Comment: Did you read through the comments on the page you link to?

Comment: Yeah, I tried following the first comment and then some type of sound error prevented the game from starting

Comment: The bottom comment refers to a sound issue with DOSBox as well.

Comment: I tried running it as an administrator, and followed the directions of the first comment, but still it did not work

Comment: I read somewhere about checking the dosbox.conf and setting the sbtype=16, but am not sure exactly how to do that

Comment: Please don't roll back my edit; links to piracy/"abandonware" sites are forbidden here, and I'm trying to help you out by removing it (and making the question more generic about getting this game to work in DOSBox in general). If you insist on keeping that link in there, your question may just be closed outright.

Answer (score 1):

Dosbox has a config file which can be modified to make this game work. Check out [This link](http://www.dosbox.com/comp_list.php?showID=2064&letter=A) for a better description of how to make this game run properly

Alternatively...

The game works great with 0.72.But first i followed the next steps to play the game:

1)In the game folder created after the installation put the univesa.exe and the vesatest.exe files.
2) Edit the "Afraid.bat" file and after the second line ("@rem run game normally")write univesa.exe and under that vesatest.exe
3)Save changes in the "Afraid.bat" file
4)Start the game using the "Afraid.bat" file (not the Afraidd.bat file, that's only a playable Demo)

These steps are necessery to make it work properly because although the game will be installed normally, the Vesa Driver will not be recognised, so that wenn the game starts the screen is really bad.
If for some reason a system can't work with univesa.exe then the vbeplus driver would be a nice alternative.

Comment: You may want to add the relevant information from the link so that your answer can still stand on itself, should the link ever go down.

Comment: Good call! Adding now